# CSS animation value doesn't "stick"

Tags: css, animation, stylesheet

In my web application, I'd like to display a message to the user after signing in or out that fades after a few seconds. I'd like to accomplish this animation with CSS.

Here is my stylesheet:

```
@keyframes fadeout {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
.flash-message {
    animation: fadeout 1s 3s;
}
```

This almost works: after a three-second delay, it begins to fade, then it takes one second to complete the animation. The problem is after the animation is complete the message reappears.

This is what I have to do to get the message to stay hidden:

```
@keyframes fadeout {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    75% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
.flash-message {
    animation: fadeout 4s;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

It seems like there should be an easier way to get the first version to work. Am I missing something or do I have to have `opacity: 0` on the class as in the second version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`animation-fill-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) and set it to `forwards`:

```
@keyframes fadeout {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
.flash-message {
    animation: fadeout 1s 3s forwards;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Jason's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27679052/8807809) explains, `animation-fill-mode` is the way to go. It defines if and how CSS properties are applied outside of the animation.

Its default setting is `none`, which applies the properties only while the animation is executing.

Setting it to `forwards` permanently applies the properties from the last keyframe value.

See the [list of values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode#Values) for more info.